Fixing my Keyboard IRQ problem as why it didnt write out the word as expected
I am currently on my way on making a simple operating system where i come to a step where i now am using the keyboard driver. However, i came across the problem where my keyboard didnt work as expected, either the interrupt is at fault whatsoever
struct KeyboardDriverState {
    bool read_extended_mode;
    bool keyboard_input_on;
    char keyboard_buffer;
} __attribute((packed));
static struct KeyboardDriverState keyboard_state = {false, false, 0};
void keyboard_state_activate(void) {
    keyboard_state.keyboard_input_on = true;
    keyboard_state.read_extended_mode = false; // Ensure extended mode is reset when activating
}

void keyboard_state_deactivate(void) {
    keyboard_state.keyboard_input_on = false;
}
void get_keyboard_buffer(char *buf) {
    if (buf != NULL && keyboard_state.keyboard_input_on) {
        *buf = keyboard_state.keyboard_buffer;
        keyboard_state.keyboard_buffer = 0; // Clear the buffer after reading
    }
}

uint8_t cursor_row = 0;
uint8_t cursor_col = 0;

void keyboard_isr(void) {
    uint8_t scancode = in(KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT);
    if (scancode == 0xE0) {
        keyboard_state.read_extended_mode = true;
        return; 
    }
    bool isBreakCode = scancode & 0x80; 

    if (!isBreakCode) {
        if (!keyboard_state.read_extended_mode) {
            char ascii = keyboard_scancode_1_to_ascii_map[scancode];
            if (ascii != 0 && keyboard_state.keyboard_input_on) {
                if (ascii == '\n') {
                    cursor_col = 0;
                    if (++cursor_row >= 25) {
                        cursor_row = 24; 
                    }
                } else if (ascii == '\b') {
                    if (cursor_col == 0 && cursor_row > 0) {
                        cursor_row--;
                        cursor_col = 79;
                    } else if (cursor_col > 0) {
                        cursor_col--;
                    }
                    framebuffer_write(cursor_row, cursor_col, ' ', 0x07, 0x00);
                } else {
                    framebuffer_write(cursor_row, cursor_col, ascii, 0x07, 0x00); 
                    if (++cursor_col >= 80) {
                        cursor_col = 0;
                        if (++cursor_row >= 25) {
                            cursor_row = 24; // Scroll or reset to top would be implemented here
                        }
                    }
                }
                framebuffer_set_cursor(cursor_row, cursor_col);
            }
        } else {
            keyboard_state.read_extended_mode = false;
        }
    }

    pic_ack(IRQ_KEYBOARD); 
}

The code above is assuming that any framebuffer func has worked as expected. Here are some of the supporting function
void io_wait(void) {
    out(0x80, 0);
}

void pic_ack(uint8_t irq) {
    if (irq >= 8) out(PIC2_COMMAND, PIC_ACK);
    out(PIC1_COMMAND, PIC_ACK);
}

void pic_remap(void) {
    // Starts the initialization sequence in cascade mode
    out(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4); 
    io_wait();
    out(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
    io_wait();
    out(PIC1_DATA, PIC1_OFFSET); // ICW2: Master PIC vector offset
    io_wait();
    out(PIC2_DATA, PIC2_OFFSET); // ICW2: Slave PIC vector offset
    io_wait();
    out(PIC1_DATA, 0b0100); // ICW3: tell Master PIC, slave PIC at IRQ2 (0000 0100)
    io_wait();
    out(PIC2_DATA, 0b0010); // ICW3: tell Slave PIC its cascade identity (0000 0010)
    io_wait();

    out(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();
    out(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();

    // Disable all interrupts
    out(PIC1_DATA, PIC_DISABLE_ALL_MASK);
    out(PIC2_DATA, PIC_DISABLE_ALL_MASK);
}

void main_interrupt_handler(struct InterruptFrame frame) {
    switch (frame.int_number) {
        case (PIC1_OFFSET+IRQ_KEYBOARD):
            keyboard_isr();
            break;
    }
}

void activate_keyboard_interrupt(void) {
    out(PIC1_DATA, in(PIC1_DATA) & ~(1 << IRQ_KEYBOARD));
}

and this is my kernel setup:
void kernel_setup(void) {
    load_gdt(&_gdt_gdtr);
    pic_remap();
    initialize_idt();
    activate_keyboard_interrupt();
    framebuffer_clear();
    framebuffer_set_cursor(0, 0);
    keyboard_state_activate();
    while (true) {
    }
}

Tbh, im still new to this material, so any help is appreciated. I would also provide another code if needed.
